# Max. realistic velocity / flow rate through pipe, limited know variables

Tags: hydraulics, hydrodynamics

I'm trying to figure out a way to calculate the maximum (realistically*) possible velocity/flow rate through a pipe, when only following limited factors are known:

- viscosity of the fluid (water)
- pipe friction factor / "roughness" of the material
- pipe length and diameter
- height difference
  A +- 100% or so estimate would already suffice.

* it should be sensibly feasable, e.g. not need extraproportional amounts of energy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll need to pick a "max pressure" to represent "feasible with regularly available pumps" .... then it's a standard, probably turbulent flow, pipe flow problem

Comment: That's an unknown as well.
So basically, to rephrase it a little: 
When (at what velocity) does the pipe (with a known diameter, I added that) start to create disproportionate friction, or to what flow rate can we pump "efficiently"/"sensibly", e.g. without extraproportional energy input/costs needed,

Comment: So here it is in a form that's probably useless to you ... https://engineeringlibrary.org/static/img/References/DOE-Fundamentals-Handbook/fluid-flow/Original/moody-chart.png

Comment: In a literal sense, it becomes "extraproportional" when you transition to turbulence. Flow is proportional to pressure in the "laminar" line on the left of the chart. The transition is predictable via dimensionless figure "Reynolds number", which can be expressed in flow,diameter,viscosity. But I'm not sure that turbulent flow is necessarily impractical - would depend on diameter probably

Comment: Alternatively, if the pipes are large (I come from miniature world, lol), the limiting factor for what is practical it might be "max power" rather than "max pressure"

Comment: Given the factors, step 1 is to look up a real material that is used in pipes that might be close.  If one does not exist, then it must not be sensible to do so.  A dose of nonsense is needed to invent, after all.